# Where to configure D compiler flags in DDT

Tags: eclipse, d, ddt

My build requires that I consider some flags, as the following command:

```
rdmd -unittest --force --main myDFile.d
```

Where is supposed to the right place for configuring required flags for D compiler in DDT?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to solve a problem that you don't need to?  D is in comparison to Java and C++ a lot simpler and you don't need an IDE for it, basically any text editor will do fine. Personally I am quite happy with Vim ;-)

Comment: @greenify: You are, considerably, right about the simple programs. But in view of elaborated codes, one might need to better IDEs to handle the project complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferably, a project is built using the DUB tool, however it is possible to customize the build command to use another tool.

In the Project Explorer, look for the Build Targets under your D project, and in the context menu, select the option "Configure Target...". There, you can customize the build command, and replace the default one (`${DUB_TOOL_PATH} build`) with another one you want. *Note that the compiler error messages must be output in the same format as the DMD output, for DDT to pick that up and create problem markers.*